# using a conditional on a knockout binded value

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

so i am using knockout to bind some set of values to a grid, using the foreach something like i have below.

```
<table id="pcc-batch-list" class="table table-striped" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Column 1</th>
                    <th>Column 2</th>
                    <th>Column 3</th>
                    <th>Column 4</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach:stuff">
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: Something1"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: Something2"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: Something3"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: Something4"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

and I want to conditionally change the color of the text displayed based on the actual value of say Something2. How would i go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try css binding http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html remember to use () in expression.

```
data-bind="text: Something1, css: {colorClass: isSomething() > 0}"
```

Comment: I think is what I want, but im having some trouble with it. Can you take a look at this fiddle and tell me where i have gone wrong? 

http://jsfiddle.net/nGgwB/5/