# Conditional viewmodel binding

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js

Hi I have started using Knockout because it is for my purpose easier then jQuery. I have used jQuery before but that made my code almost unreadable.

I have this javascript viewmodel

```
function ovm() {
    this.delStreet = ko.observable("");
    this.deliveryNotSameAsInvoice = ko.observable(false);
    this.invStreet = ko.observable("");
}
ko.applyBindings(new ovm());
```

and this HTML:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: deliveryNotSameAsInvoice" />if your invoice address is not the same as delivery</label>
<div id="delivery">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Street" 
        data-bind="value: delStreet, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" />
</div>
<div id="invoice" data-bind="visible: deliveryNotSameAsInvoice">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Street" 
        data-bind="value: invStreet, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" />
</div>
<hr/>
Delivery street: <span data-bind="text: delStreet"></span><br/>
Invoice street: <span data-bind="text: invStreet"></span><br/>
```

The thing is that I want invStreet to have the value of delStreet as long as the checkbox is unchecked. I have a [working jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jphellemons/h4wn7/3/) 
and have found this [SO question about conditional binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507085/using-a-conditional-on-a-knockout-binded-value) 
but I cannot find a good code sample. In jquery I had to bind keyup events to each textbox and depending on if the checkbox was checked, I had to set several fields. It was a lot of work. Especially with a larger 'view model'

Comment: seems like some one is having fun with Knockout.js :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a computed observable for invStreet.. like this

```
function ovm() {
     var self = this;
     this.delStreet = ko.observable("");
     this.deliveryNotSameAsInvoice = ko.observable(false);
     this.invStreet = ko.observable("");
     var invStreetCheck = ko.computed(function(){
         var checked = self.deliveryNotSameAsInvoice(),
             delStreet = self.delStreet();
         if(!checked)
             return self.invStreet(delStreet);
         return self.invStreet();
     });
 }

 ko.applyBindings(new ovm());
```

Now when the checked binding is true it will return "" else it will contain delStreet. value.

Comment: Thanks I have updated the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jphellemons/h4wn7/4/ it is almost working. It works the first time. but if you have changed your mind and decided that it is the same address it does not set the invoice address the same as delivery when you uncheck the check box. I have the feeling that my lack of caffeine in the morning is causing me not to be able to solve this minor issue myself after this help of you :)

Comment: updated it slightly.. you were returning the computed itself when checkbox is checked. That will not work. I created a computed observable just to modify the values of the invCheck. take a look. http://jsfiddle.net/sujesharukil/h4wn7/7/